# Кизил чи дерен?

Tags: вибір-слова, значення-слів

Мабуть багато з нас куштували кисло-солодкі червоні ягідки — *кизил*. Донедавна думала, що у них є ще одна назва — *дерен*. Та у [СУМ-20](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=21645&page=736) *дереном* називають поверхневий шар ґрунту, вкритий травою і трав'янистими рослинами, густо пронизаний їхніми коренями. Натомість у [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/deren) ще є визначення  дерену, як ягоди. [Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD_%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B9#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F) та [російсько-українські словники](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BB&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on) також подають обидва ці терміни. То ж чи правильно зараз називати ці ягоди *кизилом*, а чи *дереном*? Чи, можливо, обидва слова підходять?

Comment: Мені здається, що це запитання видалене несправедливо. Навпаки, воно **є зразковим складним запитанням**, і кожен з нас міг би розгубитися, поглянувши у словники. І це зразкове запитання цілком заслуговує на зразкову відповідь. Інша справа, що напіввідповідь у коментарях відлякує інших користувачів від того, щоб створити повноцінну відповідь. Тому пропоную запитання відновити, а напіввідповідь видалити. Але ваша думка, як авторки допису, є вирішальною.

Answer (score 4):

Якщо подивитися в СУМ-20 на одну позицію нижче бачимо ще одне визначення, але з іншим наголосом:

> **[ДЕРЕ́Н](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=21646&page=736)** у́, ч. **1.** Кущ або невелике дерево родини деренових із їстівними кислувато-солодкими ягодами; кизил. *Вишні, черешні,
> груші, сливи угорки, тернослив, терен та дерен – все росло густими
> купам*и (І. Нечуй-Левицький); *Кизил, або дерен, – стара культура.
> Невибаглива до ґрунтів, морозостійка, вона дістала досить велике
> поширення* (з газ.).
> **2.** збірн. Ягоди цієї рослини. *Деренівкою називають горілку, настояну на дерені* (з наук. літ.); *Повний кошик дерену.*

Інформація з підручника Заячук В.Я. "Дендрологія" *Cornus mas* L. - ***Дерен звичайний, Кизил звичайний.***

Тому правильно вживати обидва слова: і ***дерен***, і ***кизил.***

Answer (score 4):

Якщо розглядати це питання із біологічної точки зору, то, гадаю, що правильніше буде казати "кизил" чи "дерен справжній". Чому? Бо саме слово "дерен" - це цілий рід рослин до якого входить і [дерен коуса](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B0), і д[ерен-тихоокеанський](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cornus_nuttallii), і [дерен-свидина](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0) тощо (як можна зрозуміти із зображень - вони зовсім не схожі на те, що ми називаємо "кизилом").

Однак, можливо в розмовному стилі і можливо упустити ту частину "справжній". Також бачимо ці слова у [Словнику синонімів](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BB), де до них також додається ще й варіант "шайтанове дерево", а також в [Фармацевтичній енциклопедії](https://www.pharmencyclopedia.com.ua/article/2457/deren-spravzhnij).